# How to write XSLT to convert XML to XSL FO which can be used by Apache FOP to create PDF

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Basically my problem is that we have XML placed over the shared drive and we need to display the content of them on PDF . The tools and libraries we have been suggested to use is Apache FOP since it is open source and has features like supporting SVG images .

This is the approach we will be following :
( XML + XSLT(fo specific ) -> XSL FO -> Apache FOP -> PDF )

So I started looking for the content as to how to write XSLT which are XSL FO specific but couldn't find anything related to that much .
All the online tutorials are teaching how to write XSLT which are HTML specific .

So any links or suggestion would be helpful .

Comment: https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm teaches you XSLT and https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/pfux/index.htm teaches you XSL-FO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Apache FOP the best way is to start at [their homepage](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/). There is plenty of information about how to start, FAQs, examples and so on.